# SQL Cannot bulk load. The file does not exist or you don't have file access rights. Local Machine

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I try to import folder of csvs file to the SQL DB (adding column with file name). The script is below:

---

```
--BULK INSERT MULTIPLE FILES From a Folder 

--a table to loop thru filenames drop table ALLFILENAMES
drop table FPLgit
drop table ALLFILENAMES
CREATE TABLE FPLgit(
goals INT, 
shots INT,
xG FLOAT,
[time] FLOAT,
position VARCHAR(255),
h_team VARCHAR(255),
a_team VARCHAR(255),
h_goals FLOAT,
a_goals FLOAT,
[date] DATE,
id VARCHAR(255),
season VARCHAR(255),
roster_id VARCHAR(255),
xA FLOAT,
assists FLOAT,
key_passes FLOAT,
npg FLOAT,
npxG FLOAT,
xGChain FLOAT,
xGBuildup FLOAT,
Player VARCHAR)


CREATE TABLE ALLFILENAMES(Player VARCHAR(255),num varchar(255), num2 varchar(255) )

--some variables
declare @filename varchar(255),
        @path     varchar(255),
        @sql      varchar(8000),
        @cmd      varchar(1000)

-- sql don't see files in shared folder
--get the list of files to process:
INSERT INTO  ALLFILENAMES
EXEC xp_dirtree '\\LAPTOP-0H3BHMOO\understat2', 0, 1


--cursor loop
declare c1 cursor for SELECT Player FROM ALLFILENAMES where Player like '%.csv%'
open c1
fetch next from c1 into @filename
While @@fetch_status <> -1
  begin
  --bulk insert won't take a variable name, so make a sql and execute it instead:
   set @sql = 'BULK INSERT [FPLgit] FROM ''' + @filename + ''' '
       + '     WITH ( 
               FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', 
               ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'', 
               FIRSTROW = 2 
            ) '
print @sql
exec (@sql)

  fetch next from c1 into @filename
  end
close c1
deallocate c1


--Extras

--delete from ALLFILENAMES where WHICHFILE is NULL
--select * from ALLFILENAMES
--drop table ALLFILENAMES
```

---

The DB is created on local machine and i tried to login to SQL vs both SQL Server Authentication and Windows Authentication. I checked [security settings in SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTpRq.png) and also [folder permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMWat.png). I tried using both c:\ and \LAPTOP-0H3BHMOO\understat2 reference. I tried putting the file in other places (different drive/ one-drive / Dropbox). I have no idea what to do next as I did everything advised. I'm not specialist on DB and any advice would be amazing.

Comment: At a first glance I see that you are not supplying the path of file to bulk insert. @filename only contains the filename, not the path. Also is that \\LAPTOP-... remote or local? Be sure the connected account has access there.

Comment: And as a suggestion, I wouldn't use T-SQL for this, but something like C# with SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: Oh so silly mistake. Thank You. Yes, I added the path and the error is gone. However there's still something wrong in the code and I will try to correct it

Comment: @CetinBasoz thanks for the answer. Unfortunately i don't know c# at all. I'm back to my local/remote access problems. I tried to simplify the excercise bulk-importing only one csv : BULK INSERT FPLgit
FROM '‪\\LAPTOP-0H3BHMOO\understat2\Adam_Masina_1441'
WITH (FORMAT = 'CSV'
      , FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
                   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', 
                   FIRSTROW = 2 ). I try to put the file on both drives and give all the permissions and receive error 3 or error 123

Comment: I don't know the text of error 3 or 123 but I guess it is about filename. Your filename doesn't seem to be correct to me. I would expect an extension like .csv. (MS SQL server is not good at imports as much as other backends like postgreSQL but anyway it works for simple cases). It may be: BULK INSERT FPLgit FROM '‪\\LAPTOP-0H3BHMOO\understat2\Adam_Masina_1441.csv' I asked before and you didn't answer, what is \\LAPTOP... ? Is that a remove server share or local machine name? Be sure you have the path correctly and accessible.